# IOS table view cell image download

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

Hi im following a ios 10 and swift 3 class on udemy and the code of the instructor make my image to be downloaded in the table view cell very slowly (it take 15 seconde to load 5 image) with this code :

```
let url = URL(string : partyRock.ImageUrl)!

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    do{
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)

        DispatchQueue.global().sync{
            self.videoPreviewImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    } catch {
        //handle catch error
    }
```

And with this code it download very fast (the thing is that i don't understand the difference between DispatchQueue.main.sync and DispatchQueue.global().sync

```
let url = URL(string : partyRock.ImageUrl)!

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    do{
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)

        DispatchQueue.main.sync{
            self.videoPreviewImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    } catch {
        //handle catch error
    }
```

Comment: `main` thread has the highest priority...so it's the quickest. Otherwise they are both the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DispatchQueue.main.sync is Main queue: runs on the main thread and is a serial queue.
This is a common choice to update the UI after completing work in a task on a concurrent queue.

DispatchQueue.global().async is Global queues: concurrent queues that are shared by the whole system. There are four such queues with different priorities: high, default, low, and background. The background priority queue is I/O throttled. 
This is a common choice to perform non-UI work in the background

.

Answer (score 0):

```
DispatchQueue.global().async
```

means it run in background asynchronously.

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync
```

means it run in main thread synchronously.

Updating UI must always be on main thread. While others (downloading/upload data to server etc) can be sent to background.